# Bash if-then statements for pattern

Tags: bash, if-statement

Look for some help with if/else statements.  I have 2 variables that I want an if statement to see if I can match a pattern within.

```
var1="15"
var2="1|2|3|4|5"

if [[ $var1 =~ $var2 ]]
then
  matches
else
  doesn't match
fi
```

This seems to match when I try it.  I have a feeling my syntax is wrong.  I want to find a 15, not a 1 or a 5.

Comment: This script would clearly be giving you an error when you tried to run it. You should, therefore, be including that error in your question.

Comment: It doesn't give an error.  It just matches, "15" with the 1 and the 5 in var2.

Comment: What shell are you using? Is that the *exact* script? Because with bash that throws the error that @choroba is discussing avoiding about the pipe symbol on the assignment lines.

Comment: Also you use `$var` in the if but `var1` in the assignment.

Comment: Oh that is a typo in the message, but basically, the statement seems to match 15 as 1|2|3|4|5

Comment: What shell is this? That errors in bash, dash, and tcsh here. I don't have zsh to try.

Comment: It is bash shell.  I added the " " for the variables.

Comment: If the snippet in the post is not the actual code that is causing a problem that makes asking a question about it *infinitely* harder. Go fix the post.

Answer (score 1):

From `help [[`:

> When the `=~' operator is used, the string to the right of the operator
>       is matched as a regular expression.

Your syntax is fine, if a little odd. I personally would use the range `[1-5]` myself.

```
var2="[1-5]"
```

Comment: Actually it not a range.  It just numbers, it can be 1|2|5 .

Comment: Okay. But your `[[` syntax is still fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is incorrect:

```
var2=1|2|3|4|5
```

Vertical bar has a special meaning in bash. Quote the string:

```
var2='1|2|3|4|5'
```

If you want to match the whole string, you have to include `^` to match the beginning and `$` to match the end. Otherwise, any matching substring can satisfy the condition.

```
if [[ $var =~ ^($var2)$ ]]
```

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to make a difference, still matched.

Comment: @HungryFerret: Sure it matches. `15` contains `1` or `5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -q "[1-5]" <<< 15 && echo matches || echo "doesn't match"
```